# Kafka performance testing MB.sec seems too low to make sense?

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, performance-testing, metrics

Running some performance testing to compare two separate Kafka clusters. I have used a performance tool to produce in messages the same way to a topic which is named the same on both clusters.

When I run a consumer performance test I consistently get .0001 for MB.sec in one of the clusters(middle row in the image below). Whereas I will get a different value, usually higher when i run in the cluster i am comparing it with.

[image: Cluster metrics]

Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing this, my understanding is that this is mb per second consumed, why would it be consistently that number and be so low?

Thanks

Comment: You need to describe what performance tool you are running, which options you are using as well as how you collected the values you show here.

Answer (score 0):

This was a data issue, was using the confluent producer and consumer performance tools, message size is passed as a parameter. First I was running producer tool with a lower message size and hadn't realised that the consumer was consuming from the beginning of the topic where the messages were small in size.